# JSONAPI filter by date range

Tags: json-api, jsonapiframework

GET api how to send the filter parameter if the filter is a date range

eg :

```
GET /products?filter[created][ge]=2018-01-01&filter[created][le]=2017-01-01
```

Comment: JSON:API specification is agnostic about filter strategy. The query provided would be one option. What is your concrete question?

Comment: need to filter based on range, eg: date range, price range.

Comment: Are you asking, which filter strategies would support range based filters? Does your API already support filter? What server-side framework is your JSON:API powered by? There are so many open questions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON:API specification is agnostic about filter strategy. But, the next way is implemented on various libraries (like [ngx-jsonapi](https://github.com/reyesoft/ngx-jsonapi) or [neomerx json-api](https://github.com/neomerx/json-api)):

```
GET /products?filter[created][since]=2018-01-01&filter[created][until]=2020-01-01
```